# placement of the adjective/adverb いっぱい

Tags: adjectives

In the sentence: 昨日いっぱい寝たから今日は元気いっぱいです。

I want to ask about the placement of いっぱい. I want to know if it is ok to say いっぱい元気, instead of the other way around?

Is there a general rule to the placement of these modifiers?

Comment: 元気いっぱい is a fixed phrase. You can't swap around いっぱい there.

Answer (score 2):

I think いっぱい元気です is unnatural. いっぱい and たくさん as an adverb isn't usually for 元気です but とても is usually used for it.

It is easy to understand to put an adverb right before the word which is modified and it is important that you use adverbs befitted for words.

Answer (score 1):

いっぱい元気 is ungrammatical. On the other hand, すごい元気 is colloquial but perfectly natural, just like "I'm super fine" (is "super" here an adverb??)

I think 元気一杯（いっぱい）should be understood as 元気で一杯 (lit. [I am] full of power/cheerfulness.)

I think most dictionaries explain 一杯 as "full of" or "a lot of".  It's less vague than すごい which is "super" "great" or "awesome."  So it isn't acceptable to use it as an adverb.

Comment: "it isn't acceptable to use it(=いっぱい) as an adverb." >> But the いっぱい in いっぱい寝た is an adverb, isn't it? Also, [this dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/13615/meaning/m0u/) says いっぱい can be 名詞 and 副詞.

Comment: Hmm, you're right... いっぱい寝た "slept a lot" is acceptable.  I have to take it back, but I haven't come up with a logical explanation